# Publishing a CoreCLR project into an OS X Application Bundle

Tags: macos, dnx, coreclr, dnu

Are there any instructions or guides on how to publish a CoreCLR project as an OS X Application Bundle?

I'm about to start porting my desktop application from Windows to OS X and trying assess the suitability of CoreCLR to the task.  From what I've seen and given that I don't require any exising GUI libraries (I'll be custom building all that myself) it seems to be a perfectly viable option.  With previous versions of CoreCLR I've managed to get this working by manually construction the app package in a script.

What I'm wondering though is whether there's already a pre-existing method for assembling these app packages.  eg: a way to `dnu publish` to an app package.

Comment: What's an `OS X Application Package`? If you're using `dnu publish` you'll get an nupkg that can be installable if the assembly inside is a global command. Otherwise, you just get a regular nupkg. There's nothing OS X specific in that.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci An OS X Application Package (actually the correct term is Bundle) is the standard way an OS-X desktop application is packaged.  Typically just a folder with .app extension and a well defined folder structure inside.  See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(OS_X)#OS_X_application_bundles